# Clicking a Button on iPad or Android slow using Javascript

Tags: javascript, performance

If I click faster than approx 500ms, clicks get lost. I'm clicking ABABAB...
I've tried onclick as well, same problem.

- Try here:
  https://christernilsson.github.io/2021/033-MM5040/index.html
- Code:
  https://github.com/ChristerNilsson/2021/blob/main/033-MM5040/js/sketch2.js

```
body = document.getElementById "body"
d = null
command = ''
start = new Date()

f = (title) =>
    res = document.createElement 'button'
    res.innerHTML = title
    res.style = "width:300px;height:300px"
    body.appendChild res
    res.ontouchstart = =>
        t = new Date()
        command += title + "#{t-start} "
        d.innerHTML = command
        start = t

f 'A'
f 'B'
d = document.createElement 'div'
d.innerHTML = '104'
body.appendChild d
```

Comment: Using Chrome. Actually Safari performs better.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer.

```
ontouchend
```

Now down to about 150ms. So, I will use `onclick` on Windows/Mac and `ontouchend` for touch screens.